# Movie where aliens invade Earth and give all humans tags on their ears

Tags: story-identification

The movie takes place in the UK and starts with the aliens already having Earth under control, as the father of the main character goes out with a baseball bat seemingly gone crazy. The alien robot tells him he has 20 seconds to return to the house and he's vaporized. Then his children run out and the alien again tells them to return, until another human comes out, gives it some sort of code that makes it stand down.

Then later, the main characters try to use a car battery to start a PS3, which shocks one and disables their ear tag, making them essentially invisible to any sort of tracking device. They go out for a bit until they see it turn on and run back inside. After some stuff I can't remember, they stumble upon some ex-military personnel, who say that the aliens controlled the computers in modern fighter jets, and were forced to use spitfires from WW2 (the one shown is a double canopy.) Later they use it to fight, and the aliens leave (I can't remember it.) Then the guy from the beginning is told he has 20 seconds to return, while he's in the British countryside.

Comment: when you say "PS3", do you mean [PlayStation 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_3)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This must surely be *[Our Robot Overlords](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2145829/?ref_=tt_urv)*, an independent British sci-fi film from 2014, starring Gillian Anderson and Ben Kingsley.

From the [wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Overlords):

> Not long after the invasion and occupation of Earth by a race of
> powerful robots wanting human knowledge and ingenuity, humans are
> confined to their homes. Leaving without permission would be to risk
> their lives. **Monitored by the electronic implants in their necks**, the
> robot sentries are able to track the movement of humans in order to
> control them. If any person attempts to exit their home, they are
> given warnings by the robot sentries to return to their home. If he or
> she does not comply within ten seconds, they are killed.

A character, Nathan, receives an electric shock while trying to repair his PlayStation, and finds that this temporarily disables his implant. Following this discovery, a rag-tag band of people begin to fight back against the invading robots, and indeed a pivotal scene is when a [WW2 Spitfire](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-isle-of-man-23165217) is used in the combat.

Comment: Peripherally related, another series about a dominated Earth and a group of rebels that I thought of when reading the questions is the joint Beeb/Seven Australia production/adaptation of John Christopher's _The Tripods_ series.